# When home network goes down, it can ping and telnet out, but no http even locally

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am a relative amateur, so thank you for your patience. I hope this is the right place to ask about home networking questions, as [this Meta StackExchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242065/where-should-small-home-network-questions-be-asked) seems to suggest.

I am having a very weird home networking issue, and I can't find anything like it on the internet. I set up new routers a couple months ago and the network was rock solid for about 50 days. Then, just in the past couple weeks, my home network has been going down almost daily. When it goes down, I've noticed that I can still ping new domain names, shell into my remote work computer, and even telnet to old telnet sites - but *no* http works at all. I can't even http into my local router's address. If I try to connect a new device to the network by wifi or ethernet, it won't get an IP. If I manually assign it an open IP (and DNS), I can again ping and ssh and such, but again no http anywhere.

The setup is basically this: a main Netgear Nighthawk router connected to the cable modem. That main router is wired in "star" topology to two other Netgear Nighthawks, each configured as APs with fixed IP addresses. Each router has at least one other ethernet connection coming out to a Roku or desktop or whatever. They all share the same SSIDs and wifi password.

When the network goes down, I can't get into the main router (since the admin panel requires http), and I have to reboot it, and apparently Nighthawk logs get erased on reboot. (Which shocked me! What is the point of logs that don't persist across reboot?!)

I've spent many hours with Netgear, and my local ISP, and my brother (who worked in networking), apparently to no avail - so any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the router(s) is/are defective?

Comment: Is there perhaps access control configured on there? Maybe timed firewall rules or something...do you have any intermediate devices between the computer and router? any switches perhaps? Other than that, my next best guess is that it's a defective unit, especially if there's been no change to the configuration. Maybe after running for 50 days it overheated (lack of ventilation?). Just a guess - maybe check if the warranty/guarantee is still valid and consider getting it replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! There *is* a switch between the main router and the two downstream, but it's "unmanaged" - which I take to mean it couldn't be doing any firewall type stuff, right? And I sure didn't set up any firewall stuff myself.

Comment: Just in case this freakish issue applies to anyone else: after weeks of the network going down at least once every 24 hours, I did a factory reset of the main router, and have had a solid network for a week now. So I suspect it's just crappy hardware? But still no answers about why it would fail like that, after 50 days, and be fine after a reset.